# Add a .class file to a project in NetBeans

Tags: java, class, netbeans, project

Our professor provided a .class file (Out.class) we should use in our Programm. When I create a new project in NetBeans, in what directory am I supposed to copy that file and/or how do I "import" it to my project so I can use it like `Out.methodwhatever(var);`?

I have already searched for that problem, but I just found cases where people have a .jar file, but I have a .class file.

Comment: put your .class file in desired package structure, if any. then add the parent folder to class path of your project

Comment: okay, I added the Out.class file to my package where project.java and Out.class is right now. then rightclick Libraries and click "Add JAR/Folder...". then I choose the relative path "src/myproject" where the two files are located, but it doesnt work, still get "cant find symbol"

Comment: you did not get what i said. let me rephrase it, did your class file was compiled in some package ? if yes, then create that folder hierarchy and put .class file in it

Comment: today was my very first java class, so sorry for misunderstanding. if I compile with console, both files have to be in the same directory and I can use methods like "Out.println("hello");" so now special hierarchy.

Comment: in that case put .class file and your file in src directory and it shall work fine

Comment: well, the files are not located in "src/" but "src/myproject/". nevertheless -> "cannot find symbol".

Comment: Well than either move both to `src` or make `src/myproject` as your source folder or add `src/myproject` to classpath

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `Out.class` into some directory (**not** your source folder). Make sure you replicate the package structure of that class, e.g. if that class is actually `com.foobar.Out` you need to put it into e.g. `libs/com/foobar`

The right click on your project in NetBeans, select the "Libraries" category, and click on the "Add JAR/Folder". The select the e.g. the `libs` folder from the above example.