# program doesnt' recognize a .class file

Tags: java, netbeans

it's my first time working with a .class file in java, I saw that a.class file is just a compiled java code, so I figured out I should add this class to my package and it should work like a regular java class file but it didn't, I'm working with Netbeans by the way.

[image]

the problem is that I cant use this class, the main class doesn't recognize it, asking me if I want to create a Rational class to fix the error

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you want to do with the class file, but my assumption is that you got it already in this form and want to use some of it's methods.

So if this is correct you should put the file in the folder that netbeans uses to store .class files
(in my case build/classes/java/main/Testing):
[image]

IDEs almost always store .class files in a separate directory so that you don't have to deal with them, because a .class file is compiled java code and in 99% of the cases you won't touch the .class file but you will change the .java file and compile it to a class file.

Also be careful if your .class file is a part of a package you should replicate the structure of the package like answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39469429/13075001).